# Icons do not load in tab bar scene/stack

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am trying to set up my tab bar with icons, but my screen only displays the scene text without icons:

[image]

To help simplify, I made a function that takes in props of an icon name and outputs an `Icon` element called `TabIcon`, but this function doesn't run. I tested this by placing an alert in the function. I removed most scenes and only left `submit` to simplify code, it is near the bottom of the code. Here is my `router.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Scene, Router, ActionConst, Stack, Modal, Tabs } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import { View, Text, Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
//Splash Component
import Splash from '../components/Splash/Splash';

//Authentication Scenes
//removed import screens to simplify

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

//Import Store, actions
import store from '../redux/store'
import { checkLoginStatus } from "../modules/auth/actions";

import { color, navTitleStyle } from "../styles/theme";

function TabIcon(props) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Icon
          color={props.tintColor}
          name={props.iconName}
          size={26}
          />
      </View>
    )
  }

  const styles = {
    container: {
      width: 48,
      height: 42,
      padding: 5,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }
  };

export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isReady: false,
            isLoggedIn: false
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let _this = this;
        store.dispatch(checkLoginStatus((isLoggedIn) => {
            _this.setState({isReady: true, isLoggedIn});
        }));
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady)
            return <Splash/>

        return (
            <Router>
                <Scene key="root" hideNavBar
                        navigationBarStyle={{backgroundColor: "#fff"}}
                        titleStyle={navTitleStyle}
                        backButtonTintColor={color.black}
                >
                    <Stack key="Main" tabs={true} initial={this.state.isLoggedIn}>
                        //here's the scene that uses the TabIcon function//////////////////
                        <Scene key="Submit" component={Submit} title="Submit" icon={TabIcon} iconName='timer' />
                    </Stack>
                </Scene>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `<TabIcon />` work?

Comment: @riwu hi again! so how would I use that in my code? the TabIcon is a function not a class, so I cannot use it as a component right? I was referencing this from github, scroll to the very last post: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/2923

Comment: Try adding `tintColor` manually

Comment: @PritishVaidya hi Pritish! Outside of tintcolor, I need an actual icon from that function anyways, so i don't think that fixes my icon problem :/

Comment: I meant `icon={<TabIcon />}`. But from the issue it seems like a bug, refer to it for the workarounds.

Comment: @riwu yea I'm doing what the last guy says that works for him as a workaround unless im missing something in my other code that prevents his method from working in mine

Comment: @riwu i guess im mostly puzzled as to why my call to the function TabIcon isn't being called

Answer (score 1):

In my solution it worked: if `Icon={myIcon}` is not working, try `tabBarLabel={myIcon}`

```
                <Scene key="tabs" hideNavBar tabs={true} 
                tabBarStyle={}>
                    <Scene key="roomTab" tabBarLabel={roomIcon} >
                        <Scene 
                            key="rooms"
                            hideNavBar
                            component={Rooms}
                            initial={true}
                        />
                    </Scene>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put a style like the following one, the same thing happened to me and adding it was fixed

```
style={{height:26, width:26}}
```

in this part

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Icon
      color={props.tintColor}
      name={props.iconName}
      size={26}
      />
  </View>
```

so ...

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Icon
      style={{height:26, width:26}}
      color={props.tintColor}
      name={props.iconName}
      size={26}
      />
  </View>
```